# How to minimize Time Requirement while updating 2000 rows in SQLite

Tags: android, sql, database

I have SQLite with more than 20,000 rows.

When I am adding new data ( 2000 rows) it takes 2 Sec.

But When I am trying to update same 2000 rows it takes almost 10 mins.

I am using following code for updating

```
 public int update_ItemPriceDetails(Struct_ItemPrice_Details mStruct_ItemPrice_Details, String ItemId) 
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            //values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
            values.put(Key_ITEM_Id, mStruct_ItemPrice_Details.get_Item_Id()); // Struct_Contact Name
            values.put(Key_PRICE_Id, mStruct_ItemPrice_Details.get_Price_Id()); // Struct_Contact Name
            .
.
.



            // updating row
            int update=db.update(TABLE, values, 
                    Key_PRICE_Id + "=?",
                    new String[] {mStruct_ItemPrice_Details.get_Price_Id()});
        //  db.close();
            return update;

        }




Database_ItemPrice_Details db = getInstance(context);
        SQLiteDatabase DB = db.getWritableDatabase();

        try {
            DB.beginTransaction();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        for(int i=0i<2000;i++)
        {
         update_ItemPriceDetails(List.get(i), "")
        }
    try {       
        Database_ItemPrice_Details_Kolkata db = getInstance(context);
        SQLiteDatabase DB = db.getWritableDatabase();

        DB.setTransactionSuccessful();
        DB.endTransaction();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: For working code, you may have better responses on [codereview.se]

Comment: Have you created an index on the `Key_PRICE_Id` column?

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Do not call `getWritableDatabase()` inside the loop. There should be exactly one call to `getWritableDatabase()` in your entire code snippet.

Step #2: Use transactions properly:

```
db.beginTransaction();

try {
  // your SQL
  db.markTransactionSuccessful();
}
catch (Exception e) {
  // do whatever logging you want to do, etc.
}
finally {
  db.endTransaction();
}
```

*Probably* what you have will not impact performance, but since proper transactions are very important for performance, it is worth examining. Particularly for the duration that you describe, it feels like the transaction is not working correctly.

Step #3: As TobyLL suggests, make sure that you have an index on your column indicated by `Key_PRICE_Id` in Java.

Step #4: Avoid creating `ContentValues` inside the loop, to avoid creating excessive garbage.

Step #5: Use Traceview to determine where you are spending your remaining time.

Comment: I made changes as per your point 1 and 2, Still it is taking 1 min for 2000 updates (10 min for 20,000) . Will maaking changes as per your rest of points will make drastic time difference ?

Comment: @Tushar: #3, yes. #4, possibly, but I doubt it. #5 will help you determine where your problem is.